deployment issue
Code
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

contract FundMe{
    uint256 public fundAmounts=3;
    function fundMe()  public payable{
        fundAmounts=fundAmounts+2;
        require(msg.value > 1e9,"minimum amount must be 1 ether");
        

    }

}


Error
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: FundMe.fundMe() 0xb27...07c2cvalue: 0 weidata: 0xb6a...324e0logs: 0hash: 0x19b...d2a43
transact to FundMe.fundMe errored: Error occurred: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "minimum amount must be 1 ether".
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the tr



This error is not coming from deployment. This is from the function fundMe().
You require the function call to be funded with 1e9 wei
require(msg.value > 1e9,"minimum amount must be 1 ether");
which means when you call the fundMe function you need to send that value. You can do so by entering 1000000000 in the value field here 

before calling the function.
